# How to fine-tune dirt4 4WD car controls for snowy tracks?

Tags: dirt-4

I am driving with Logitech G25 wheel with manual and clutch setup. My car is a 4WD Lancer, and I got, in all other rallies, 1st or 2nd place up until this point. However, driving on snow is proving difficult.

After some research, I realized that I need to fine-tune my car for snow.

My current fine-tuned setup looks like the following, but it doesn't cut it:

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am having a hard time staying on the road. Could anyone show me what settings to use and why?